# How to see old YouTube comment notifications?

Tags: youtube

There are similar questions like that already but they are very outdated and youtube has significantly changed since then.

I sometimes click on the "notifications" icon and see that there are some comments notifications. But then if for any reason I close that notifications box (for example by accidental page reload), I can't seem to access those notifications anymore.

Is there any way to see the previous comment notifications?

Comment: Is it possible the comment was deleted?

Comment: Seems unlikely but in that specific case I didn't get to see what the comment was at all because I clicked on a video link, and clicked on notifications while it was loading. And it loaded the video the moment I saw the notifications.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of 23/12/21, the only way I know of seeing all your notifications, specifically the older ones that don't show up on the notifications bell, can be found by going through the History tab, on the main YouTube menu. Once on the History page, look to the right of the page, make sure that you have "Watch history" selected. Then, just underneath, under "Manage All History", click on "Comments" and it will take you to another page where you will see all the comments you've ever made.

Comment: Thanks.  The UX/UI provided by big tech never ceases to disappoint me.  But I found what I was looking for eventually, with the help of your answer.